# I can't open my second activity in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I am trying to create a small app with two activities, but when i go to my second activity, my app has stopped.
There is no error in code, but when i start my second activity from my app, it crashed.
[image: And it start showing this error log "FATAL Exception"]

Here is my detail Activity code, when i open this activity from my virtual device, and it has stopped.

```
   package com.example.sj.dgapps3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected String name ;
    protected int pos;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        name = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.Name);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        textView.setText(name);

        pos = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.Position, 0);
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.position);
        textView1.setText(pos);


        int qual = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.Qualification, 0);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qualification1);
        textView1.setText(qual);

        int exp = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.Expertise, 0);
        TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.expertise1);
        textView1.setText(exp);

        int con = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.Contact, 0);
        TextView textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact1);
        textView1.setText(con);

        /*String pic = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.Pic);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.empPic);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageView);*/

        /*ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.empPic);
        int res = getResources().getIdentifier(teamDetails.getPic(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        imageView.setImageResource(res);*/




        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And here is my XML code for my detail activity.

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/position"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/qualification"
        android:text="Qualification:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expertise"
        android:text="Expertise:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/qualification"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/contact"
        android:text="Contact:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/expertise"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/qualification1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/qualification"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/qualification"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/expertise1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/expertise"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/qualification1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/qualification1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/contact1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/contact"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/qualification1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/qualification1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where is java code ??

Comment: post your second activity code

Comment: add xml and code in your question section

Comment: DetailActivity code?

Comment: Please copy and paste the text here. Don't take screeenshots of that. Plus you've cut off the necessary information of the error. Also, Android Studio can open your Activity just fine, it's the device that can't.

Comment: please share your `androidmanifest`, you might have forgotten to instantiate the said activity

Comment: @Scar Can you read the picture? That's not the problem

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i have updated my question with my detail activity java code.

Comment: @sasikumar i've updated my question.

Comment: Sorry for not putting everything in it, do let me know if anything you want to see.
Thanks for your help everyone :)

Comment: Make sure add your <activity> in Manifest file..

Answer (score 2):

It looks like in `DetailActivity` on line 30 you're trying to set the text of a TextView like so:

`textView.setText(0)`

When passing an integer to `setText`, it refers to a string resource. In this case, `0` is not a valid string id.

Consider passing a string (`textView.setText("0")`) or creating that string resource in strings.xml and refer to it in code like so: `textView.setText(R.string.myString)`.

Comment: `String.valueOf(number)` is worth mentioning in case the text is being set with a variable

Comment: @siger I've added my java and XML code too, kindly see if you can find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you assign  int (qual,exp,con) values to setText().

**Convert int to string** then set as TexView text.

```
int qual = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.Qualification, 0);
TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qualification1);
textView1.setText(String.valueOf(qual));

int exp = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.Expertise, 0);
TextView textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.expertise1);
textView1.setText(String.valueOf(exp));

int con = getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.Contact, 0);
TextView textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact1);
textView1.setText(String.valueOf(con));
```

Answer (score -3):

Did you check your manifest?
You need to add your activity there.

Comment: That's not the error message. ResourceNotFound is different than that error

Comment: At least you could provide some code... So it would be easier for us to help you. It think you should revise your DetailActivity.java line 30. Thats for now the only help I can give you

Comment: The error contains all the details needed, actually. The other answer has that covered

Comment: That line in blue (logcat) , Does it mean where the error is? (im new on android dev)

Comment: Yup the hyperlink will go to the code on that line 30 of that activity, then the "Caused by" reason is the most important, then the few lines around the blue line are also important because it says what code is being ran. Sadly StackOverflow doesn't teach debugging too well :)

Comment: I see... Thanks , I appreciate, I ddnt know that

Comment: It's Ok Guys he is new to SO. Don't Be on Back!!